# watchOS4 global tint not applied properly

Tags: watchos-4

watchOS4 App's global tint seems to not applied sometimes.

watchOS4 temporarily changes app's tint to gray while it comes to front-most from background. After the app got into front-most, watchOS seems to change gray to it's original tint color.

However, watchOS4 sometimes not changes tint color to original one. Still grayed.

I found some scenarios:

1. Install watchOS app and watchOS launches it background automatically due to update complication: 100% grayed.
2. When update existing watchOS App that is running through TestFlight: 100% grayed.
3. Kill the app and re-launch: Works well.
4. When user launches the app that is not running in background: Works well.

PS. All tests are performed with 1st gen. (mentioned as series 0)

Any clues will be welcomed.

Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is fixed in watchOS 4.2 beta 1.